# KDE installer localization

Tags: kde, internationalization, localization

I'm making a new Kubuntu remaster using Ubuntu Customization Toolkit (For fun, of course). It's supposed to be in localized and some extra packages are installed by default.

The problem is that installer is not fully translated by Persian localization team, and I can't find out how to do the rest. I've cloned localization repository:

```
svn co svn://anonsvn.kde.org/home/kde/trunk/l10n-kde4/fa/message
```

And then started to do actual translation. There are two problems:

1. Installer resources are not included. I suppose there are placed in `isolinux/[LANGCODE].tr` files.
2. Resources for applications are not fully included. For messages of [Step](https://edu.kde.org/step/) physical simulator are not included.

So what I need to to do is:

1. Find Installer resources and update installation medium.
2. Find something like Qt's lupdate to scan code and update .po files. Oh, and also I can't find source codes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but the installer UI seems to reside in the [ubiquity-slideshow-ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity-slideshow-ubuntu) package, and there is a [Persian translation interface for Kubuntu](https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu/vivid/+source/ubiquity-slideshow-ubuntu/+pots/ubiquity-slideshow-kubuntu/fa/+translate) at Launchpad.